# How to validate depends on other value in php laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

i have a validation in laravel like this

```
$this->validate($request, [
   "brief_table" => "required"
]);
```

then i want to check other validation depends on brief_table value
like if brief_table value is 'logo' i want to check

```
[
            "service" => "required",
            "category" => "required",
            "logo" => "required",
            "description" => "required",
            "industry" => "required",
            "vision_mission" => "required",
            "logo_format" => "required",
            "symbol" => "required",
            "color" => "required",
            "clr" => "required",
            "designer_note" => "required",
            "business_card" => "required"
        ]
```

if brief value is annual report then i want to apply the other rule

but i need to check if the brief_table value is exists or not.

i tried to use double validate like

```
$this->validate($request, ["brief_table" => "required"]);
$this->validate($request, $this->getValidationRule($request->brief_table));
```

the first one is working but the 2nd one isnt working.

Comment: it's my mistake that the 2nd validation rule isnt in the right format
sorry.

Comment: Quwawi brief_table value is `optional` or `required` ?

Comment: Simply check with `if()` & make multiple `$this->validate()`

Comment: it's already working.
brief table is required (get brief_table value from user input).
then i need to check other validation which the rule is depends on brief_table value.

i just miss some litle thing in my code. but its working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just check the value of brief_table and then apply different rules depending on the result?

Here the first rules would apply if brief_table == logo. And if it's something else (including null) the other rule should apply.

```
if ($request->input('brief_table') == 'logo') {
    $this->validate($request, [
        "brief_table" => "required",
        "service" => "required",
        "category" => "required",
        "logo" => "required",
        "description" => "required",
        "industry" => "required",
        "vision_mission" => "required",
        "logo_format" => "required",
        "symbol" => "required",
        "color" => "required",
        "clr" => "required",
        "designer_note" => "required",
        "business_card" => "required"
    ]);
} else {
    $this->validate($request, [
        "brief_table" => "required",
        ... other rules ...
    ]);
}
```